# New Dell XPS Developer Editiotion Keyboard Shortcut 2016

Tags: unity, 16.04, dell, xps

A couple of days ago I got my new XPS Developer edition and I am really happy with it. It comes by default with Ubuntu 16.04.

The only issue, that is really small, is that super(win) key does not work for the Unity shortcuts and I don't know why.

I already try to change the shortcuts keys and reset it without any luck.
I use the keyboard layout chart to confirm that I was pressing super key ( super key L is pressed, I don't know if this should be the issue ).

Any recommendation would be really appreaciate it.

Answer (score 8):

At the end was an Dell Application that was causing that Super Key to don't work properly.

The solution can be found here : https://en.cristiantala.cl/dell-xps-developer-edition-ubuntu-dash-super-key/

But debriefing :

```
sudo apt-get remove dell-super-key
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

After that just go to the Compiz Settings, search for Unity, Select Launcher and just assign the Super Key for the Dash  menu.